# Getting list of choices for a django model field to a vue.js frontend

Tags: django, vue.js, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using django restframework on the backend to create an API which I access from the frontend using vue.js. I have a 'Post' model that stores text and also has a field 'privacy_settings'. I have defined the privacy setting field as follows:

What is the best way to retrieve the options/choices on the frontend when creating a new post?

```
ONLYME = 'ME'
FRIENDS = 'FR'
PUBLIC = 'PU'
POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES = (
    (ONLYME, 'Onlyme'),
    (FRIENDS, 'Friends'),
    (PUBLIC, 'Public'),
)
privacy_setting = models.CharField(
max_length = 2,
choices = POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES,
default = ONLYME
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered the approach of separate all the choices dictionaries you are going to use throughout your app inside another different file like `choices.py`?

Anyway, creating an specific view like this with the opened action **GET** expecting a nice `query_parameter` plus a curated list of available `options` here would be the best bet.

```py
    ONLYME = 'ME'
    FRIENDS = 'FR'
    PUBLIC = 'PU'
    POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES = (
        (ONLYME, 'Onlyme'),
        (FRIENDS, 'Friends'),
        (PUBLIC, 'Public'),
    )

    class ChoiceView(GenericAPIView):

        available_dicts = {
            "POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES": POST_PRIVACY_CHOICES,
        }

        def get(self, request):
            option = request.GET.get("option", None)
            if option is not None and option in self.available_dicts:
                result_list = []
                chosen_dict = available_dicts[option]
                for i in chosen_dict:
                    key, value = i
                    tmp = {"key": key, "value": value}
                    result_list.append(tmp)
                return Response(result_list, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"Error": "Empty or invalid option given"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Anytime you want to retrieve a list of choices, it will be easier and faster!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I think this is more or less the best option for my issue. I guess there is no way to avoid making a separate api call to retrieve the options. Also regarding your suggestion to move all choices in a separate class, thats also a good idea. i was basically following the official django docs word for word and my approach is the preferred way according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [django-js-choices](https://pypi.org/project/django-js-choices/).

This will automatically read all the choices in your models and create a Javascript file where you can use `Choices.pairs("choice_field")` to get all the value/label pairs and `Choices.display("choice_field", "field_value")` to get the label of that choice.